# Play! with JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, playframework

I am using Play! framework 1.2.4 and I have a question regarding JDBC connection. I use DB.getConnection() method to get a connection, and create a PreparedStatement. So I would like to know if I need to close PreparedStatement and ResultSet just like normal JDBC practises. Thanks in advance.

Regards,

K.H

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is certainly no harm in doing so. So my advise is to follow the standard JDBC practices - closing the acquired resources in reverse order (resultset -> statement -> connection).